# Asynchronous DOM tree traversal with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, asynchronous, tree-traversal

I would like to perform a long running, node-by-node walk of the DOM, calling a function on each node, but without making the browser unresponsive.
So I'm thinking asynchronous is the way to go.

I think jQuery Deferred objects could provide a solution, but I haven't managed to come up with one yet.

Can anyone give an example of how you could do this with jQuery (or another library, if one particularly stands out as suitable; or pure Javascript and DOM methods).

To further complicate things, I would like the ability to traverse in different orders, for example postorder, but not yet a requirement.

Comment: google "multithread javascript" you can find libraries and answers there (searched the same thing myself today...)

Comment: what do you have in mind?  honestly just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this recursively with setTimeout. Since Javascript is single threaded you can create the illusion of having multiple threads by relinquishing the thread periodically. Calling setTimeout will queue the remaining work and process any outstanding events before continuing.

Here's a working example with jQuery:

```
function traverse(node, visitor, root) {
    if (root === undefined)
        root = node;

    visitor(node, function() {
        if (!node.length)
            return;

        let nextNode;
        if (node.children().length) {
            nextNode = node.children().first();
        } else {
            nextNode = node;
            do {
                if (root.length && nextNode.length && nextNode[0] == root[0]) {
                    nextNode = $();
                    break;
                } else if (nextNode.next().length) {
                    nextNode = nextNode.next();
                    break;
                } else {
                    nextNode = nextNode.parent();
                }
            } while (nextNode.length);
        }

        setTimeout(function() { traverse(nextNode, visitor, root); }, 200);
    });
}
```

This will call `visitor` with all DOM nodes in depth-first pre-order traversal, then call `visitor` with an empty jQuery object to indicate that it's done. `visitor` must call its second parameter to proceed with traversal:

```
traverse($('#rootNode'), function(node, proceed) {
    if (!node.length) {
        console.log('done with traversal');
        // no proceed() call at the end
    } else if (node.hasClass('my-class')) {
        // let's say that this click triggers an AJAX request that makes a node visible later in traversal
        node.trigger('click');
        proceed(); // continue traversal
    } else if (node.hasClass('ajax-response-container')) {
        function checkIfVisible() {
            if (node.is(':visible')) {
                // yay, ajax response arrived
                console.log('AJAX response', node.html());
                // continue traversal
                proceed();
            } else {
                // wait for ajax node to become visible
                window.requestAnimationFrame(checkIfVisible);
                // no proceed() call - don't continue traversal yet
            }
        }

        checkIfVisible();
    } else {
        // continue traversal for any other node encountered
        proceed();
    }
});
```

Comment: Isn't there a problem with `while(parent && !parent.next())` because parent is a jQuery object so it's always non-null.  Also, doesn't it need to stop going up to parents above the passed in node?

Comment: @jfriend00 You are correct. You would want to check the length of parent instead. Also correct about checking whether the parent is the starting node. The code was meant more as psuedo code tho to get the OP started.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use HTML5, some browsers have support for web workers. https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_web_workers
This may be an option.  You may be able to pass the DOM as document to the methods and go from there.

Comment: Web workers cannot access the DOM so they won't help with a "long running node-by-node walk of the DOM".

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at https://github.com/wilsonpage/fastdom/ which does exactly that, async ops in the dom.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this approach

https://gist.github.com/stelf/4b6935071447724c7066

based on Kris Kowal's Q library. Basically similar to SynXsiS's idea, but a bit more structured in terms of Promises/Deffered objects.